# Posting a JSON Object with a list of list of booleans against a Spring Boot rest service

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson

I have a Python Client which can post a json Object to my Spring Boot server.

The client code looks like this:

```
jsonTest = {
    "room": lists
}
json_list = json.dumps(jsonTest)

requests.post('http://localhost:8082/room', json=json_list)
```

And the client code like this:

The Room Class:

```
public class Room {

   @JsonProperty("room")
   private List<List<Boolean>> roomList;

   public Room(List<List<Boolean>> roomList) {
       this.roomList = roomList;
   }

   public List<List<Boolean>> getRoomList() {
       return roomList;
   }

   public void setRoomList(List<List<Boolean>> roomList) {
       this.roomList = roomList;
   }
}
```

The Controller:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

   @PostMapping(value = "/room")
   public Room room(@RequestBody Room newRoom) {
       return newRoom;
   }
}
```

When the post is executed i get the following error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class de.lukas.broetje.findaway.movement.Room]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `de.luckes.findaway.movement.Room` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"room": [[false, false,...(a lot of content here)....., false, false]]}')
> at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]] with root cause

My Question is: Why does Jackson does not convert the JSON object?

Comment: Please update the question with complete error and complete json

Answer (score 0):

as you already provide the below custom constructor no default, no-args constructor will be generated by Java compiler.

```
public Room(List<List<Boolean>> roomList) {
       this.roomList = roomList;
}
```

the error message says that you need to provide a default, no-args constructor in your `Room` class, e.g.

```
public Room() {
}
```

so add the default, no-args constructor explicitly and you should be good to go ;-)

Comment: Thank you :) But is just obscured another problem. But i solved it.